# Dotnet application build using Docker-compose

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

I am looking for some help in build a robust docker-compose file.
I have my docker images in my private repository, Before i used to pull all images and then used to try docker run commands individually to build a container. Now i am planning to build a docker-compose file.

Manual commands used:

```
docker run --restart unless-stopped -t -d --name test_rest -p 9095:80 --entrypoint dotnet test_rest script_var.Core.dll test_var:MongoSource=mongodb://192.168.22.22 KafkaReceiveStream:KafkaBroker=192.168.22.22:9092 KafkaReceiveStream:KafkaTopic=testevents KafkaSendStream:KafkaTopic=test_key KafkaSendStream:KafkaBroker=192.168.22.22:9092

docker run --restart unless-stopped -t -d --name test_app1 -p 9096:80 --entrypoint dotnet test_app1 script_var.Core.dll test_var:MongoSource=mongodb://192.168.22.22

docker run --restart unless-stopped -t -d --name test_app2 --entrypoint dotnet test_app2 script_var.Core.dll
```

Now I would like to build a docker-compose file out from above commands.

```
version: '2.1'
networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
services:
  test_reste:
    image: test_rest
    ports:
      - "9095:80"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
  test_app1:
    image: test_app1
    ports:
      - "9096:80"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
  test_app2:
    image: test_app2
    networks:
      - mynetwork
```

How can we add the entry point in docker-compose file, i tried to add

```
image: test_rest
   entrypoint:
     - dotnet
     - test_rest
     - script_var.Core.dll
     .
     .
     .
```

This is the error i got:

```
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
test_rest_1  |   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

Can some one help me how can we solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ended up figuring this out but the place to put your `ENTRYPOINT` is in the `Dockerfile`, not the `docker-compose` file.

So your `Dockerfile` might look something like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 9095
EXPOSE 9096

FROM pathToYourImage AS build
WORKDIR /src

# ... you should already have a Dockerfile for your private repos images? ...

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test_rest.dll"]
```

EDIT 1: My apologies, you can add entrypoint to your compose. For example:

`entrypoint: ["dotnet", "test_rest.dll"]`